# GCD ( greatest common divisor ) of a list/array of numbers in LISP

Tags: lisp

How can I make the GCD of a list of numbers in LISP? I want to calculate the Greatest Common Divisor of a given input list.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Try combining [`gcd`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_gcd.htm) with [`apply`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Common Lisp has a `gcd` function which takes any number of arguments.  So one way is to use that function and `apply` in an obvious way.

That's a fairly bad way though.  A better way is to rely on the fact that GCD is an associative function.  This means that gcd(a, gcd(b, c)) = gcd(gcd(a, b), c).  That leads you to a very neat approach for computing the gcd of arbitrary length lists:

Given a list l, and a current gcd g, then

- if l is empty the result is g;
- if l is not empty then it is of the form (a . r), and the result is now the gcd  of r using a current value of gcd(g, a).

As an additional trick: once you've got `1` as the current value, you can stop.

If you are required to *write* the two argument function, here are two implementations which work for non-zero natural numbers:

```
(defun gcd/euclidean (a b)
  (declare (type (integer 0) a b))
  (cond
   ((= a 0) b)
   ((= a b) a)
   ((> a b) (gcd/euclidean (mod a b) b))
   (t (gcd/euclidean b a))))

(defun gcd/euclid (a b)
  (declare (type (integer 1) a b))
  (cond
   ((= a b) a)
   ((> a b) (gcd/euclid (- a b) b))
   (t (gcd/euclid b a))))
```

One of these is much better than the other!